# Route parameter includes question mark

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I would like to use a URL as route parameter in Laravel. Here is the route declaration from my `web.php`

```
<?php 
Route::get('/url/{id}/{url?}', 
   'URLController@find')
    ->where('url', '(.*)');
```

This is working fine if the "url" parameter doesn't have its' own query parameters. Yet this is not working as expected:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/productsdetails?prodid=44296
```

When I pass the above URL, it just get the `http://www.somedomain.com/productsdetails` part of the parameter. Laravel couldn't resolve the part after the question mark.

Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: Anything after the `?` is part of the `Request` and not the URL. Use `\Request::get("prodid")` to get it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This solution is absolute in terms of specific parameters. But I don't know the exact parameters before-hand. For example `prodid` could be something else like `actionID`. Moreover as you kow some URL's have multiple query parameters like so: `?someParameter=1243?anotherParameter=abcd?lastParameter=789` and so on

Comment: `\Request::all()` has all the parameters. Also the correct URL parameters are `?parameter1=X&parameter2=Y&....`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I can get the parameters as array with this facade. Perfect!